# How to correctly take an element of a vector-valued function?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

I have a vector-valued function whose arguments, for some reasons, are forced to be numeric by adding `?NumericQ`. I can correctly take a particular element of the vector value of the function if I input specific numberic arguments. For example,

```
f[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := {-x, -y, -y - 1}

f[1, 2]
{-1, -2, -3} (* output *)

f[1, 2][[1]]
-1  (* output *)
```

So far so good. But sometimes I need to leave the arguments symbolic and specify them by rules. That creates mistakes. For example:

```
f[x, y][[1]] /. {x -> 1, y -> 2}
1 (* output *)
```

Mathematica  executes `Part` before applying the rules, which is not what I want. The problem is not solved even if I use `Evaluate`:

```
Evaluate[f[x, y]][[1]] /. {x -> 1, y -> 2}
1 (* output *)
```

Is there a simple built-in function to correct the order (replacing x, y using the rules before evaluating the function and taking part)? Currently I need to define a new module function to take the particular element and then work with the new function. I'm wondering if there is a simpler way. Thank you!

Comment: `Unevaluated[f[x, y][[1]]] /. {x -> 1, y -> 2}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Indexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Indexed) for this purpose:

```
f[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := {-x, -y, -y-1}

Indexed[f[x,y],1] /. {x -> 1, y -> 2}
```

> -1

Comment: Thanks Carl and kglr! Both Unevaluated and Indexed work for my purpose.